# How to add login with google on my Hexo Blog?

Tags: blogs, google-authentication, hexo

I recently created a blog using Hexo and using the Aurora [theme](https://github.com/auroral-ui/hexo-theme-aurora). I would like to know how to add the connection with google so that we can leave comments. I haven't found anything on the internet as a plugin or tutorial to implement this

Answer (score 0):

Your request is two-fold:

1. You want people to have to login using Google to be able to post those comments.
2. You want the ability to leave comments on your Hexo blog.

Google themselves do not have a commenting service but you can use a number of other services that provide comment functionality for the pages of your blog.

I personally use and recommend [Disqus](https://disqus.com). It's very customisable allowing people to login with a number of different providers depending on the settings you choose. This includes Google login.

But you can allow people to login using Twitter, Facebook and other services to post the comments to your blog. You can see an example of this in action [here at the bottom of the post](http://strawdogs.co/2020/10/How-to-Integrate-fzf-into-ZSHell/).

There are other options besides Disqus but the Hexo creator himself uses Disqus and most themes come with it built in as standard.

There's even a setting `comments` in the main config file to enable this.

However if Disqus isn't to your liking you may consider [GitTalk](https://github.com/snowdreams1006/hexo-plugin-gitalk) and [Facebook comments](https://github.com/RichardJECooke/hexo-fbcomments) plugins.

It seems your theme only supports Valine and GitTalk as standard so you could use those [by following the instructions given [on the themes documentation page](https://aurora.tridiamond.tech/guide/plugins.html#comments).

I wouldn't recommend Valine due to a XSS security vulnerability that's not been fixed so far though.

Implementing Disqus on the theme is very simple and upon sign up all the information and tutorials you would need are provided by them.